# jQuery Plugin to use Wordpress functions in AJAX request

Tags: plugins, functions, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using [Chained Selects jQuery Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) to create **multiple chained selection fields**. I'm using the *remote version* of the plugin to build the related options by means of **AJAX request** from a **separate PHP file**. So basically it works by calling the following code:

```
$("#field2").remoteChained("#field1", "/data/json.php");
```

### What I would like to do

I would like to **use Wordpress' functions** in the **PHP file** (in this case: **/data/json.php**) to create the options **dynamically**. But I **do not** want to use `mysql_query()` to search through the database.

I understand that in Wordpress you have to use **admin-ajax.php**. But I'm not sure how to **integrate it with the plugin above**.

### Sample Case

**For this example, let's just use Wordpress' category**. So the two select fields will be the category field and the sub-category field. The latter one will relate to the former one, ie. the parent category.

> Note: In my actual project, I'm using [PODs CMS plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/) to
>   create a list of items from a **content type** *(which is like custom
>   post type)* that is related to another list of items in another
>   **content type**. These will become the options in my chained select fields.

### What I have tried so far

1. The HTML:

   ```
   <?php
   wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=0&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&show_option_none=Main Categories&name=field1');
   ?>
   <select name="field2" id="field2"></select>
   ```
2. Call the scripts (in `functions.php`):

   ```
   function the_scripts() {
       // The Chained Selects jQuery Plugin
       wp_enqueue_script('chained_select', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.chained.remote.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

       // The script to call the action
       wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery','chained_select'), false, true);

       // code to declare the URL to the file handling the AJAX request
       wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
   }

   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_scripts', 100);
   ```
3. The code to call the action (in `scripts.js`):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function (){

       jQuery.post(
           the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
               {
                   action : 'myajax-submit'
               }
               ,function( response ) {
                   $("#field2").remoteChained("#field1", the_ajax_script.ajaxurl);
               }
       );

   });
   ```
4. The action (in `functions.php`):

   ```
   function get_options() {

       $response[""] = "--";

       if ($_GET["field1"]) {

           $categories =  get_categories('child_of='.$_GET['field1'].'&hide_empty=0');

           $response[""] = "--";
           foreach ($categories as $cat) {
               $response[$cat->term_id] = $cat->cat_name;
           }

       };

       print json_encode($response);

       exit;
   }

   add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'get_options' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'get_options' );
   ```

This whole thing doesn't work in that the jQuery plugin isn't doing it's job. How can I communicate Wordpress with this plugin?

Thanks in advanced.